# How to return text based on the max value on another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have a table that contains multiple ID & products.
In cell F2 & F3, I would like to return the product based on the max value (largest sales in column C).

Is there any Excel function I can use to get this?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to return the product, iD or both?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this formula:

```
=INDEX(B3:D9,MATCH(MAX((B3:B9=F3)*D3:D9),D3:D9,0),2)
```

Note: This is an array formula; CTRL + SHIFT = ENTER keys must be pressed together

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZwST.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm amending your example to accommodate the edge case where IDs ABC and XYZ have the same maximum sales:

[image]

Enter the following formula in `F2` and copy down: `=XLOOKUP($E2&MAXIFS($C$2:$C$8,$A$2:$A$8,$E2),$A$2:$A$8&$C$2:$C$8,$B$2:$B$8)`

Alternatively, find the product for each ID simultaneously with this dynamic array formula:
`=XLOOKUP(E2:E3&MAXIFS(C2:C8,A2:A8,E2:E3),A2:A8&C2:C8,B2:B8)`

With older versions of Excel, instead type
`=INDEX(B2:B8,MATCH(E20&MAX(C2:C8*(A2:A8=E2)),A2:A8&C2:C8,0))`
and hit `Ctrl-Shift-Enter` instead of `Enter`.

Now consider the edge case where a few products for a particular ID are tied for maximum sales. The above formulas return whichever product is listed first. The following dynamic array formula returns them all:
`=FILTER(B2:B8,(A2:A8=E2)*C2:C8=MAXIFS(C2:C8,A2:A8,E2))`

[image]